# R-script, issue with data_path <- paste

Tags: r, tidyverse, qiime

This is the top of my R script which was shared on qiime forums. The script is meant to make a metadata file for multiple fastq files.
How do I edit it to run without needing editing every time but I cant seem to tell it to use the current working director

Here is the problem code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(tidyverse)

data_path <- paste ("./", "Data", sep = "/")
```

And its error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "direction", value = "forward") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
Calls: [<- -> [<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `setwd()`. Am I right in thinking you always want to set the  working directory to "./Data/" ?  If so, `setwd("Data/")` should work.

Comment: Also - and I don't know anything about conda installed R-Env - but I think you're curly double quotes might be messing up your code.

Comment: so I changed the line starting `datapath` to; 
`data_path <- paste (setwd("Data/"), "Data", sep = "/")
I got a similar error;
`unexpected input in "data_path <- paste (setwd("Data/")  �"

Comment: Hello Gus, welcome to stack overflow. I think the error is caused by "wrong" quotation-marks. If you take a close look on them they are not the standard quotation marks but some other characters. So R doesn't read them as quotation-mark and therefore the text between not as a string but some object. Just deleat them and make them new and you should have a running line of code. (just for comparision: the quotemarke used: “ and  the standard one ")

Comment: just as @ forestfanjoe allready explained but i didn't read before posting :D shame on me.

Comment: I think you're definitely onto something, but its not fixed it ='(

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(tidyverse)

data_path <- paste "(setwd(Data/)" "Data", sep = "/")
SamplesF <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = “*.R1.fastq.gz”, all.files = FALSE,
full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE,
ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no… = FALSE)`

Comment: `── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
Error: unexpected string constant in "data_path <- paste "(setwd(Data/)""
Execution halted
(R-Env) qiime2@qiime2core2018-8:~/nanopore_reads/outputs/workspace/pass/barcode01$ `

Comment: `Error: unexpected string constant in "data_path <- paste "(setwd(Data/)""
Execution halted `

Comment: Thanks btw, I cannot believe I've never been on stack overflow before, its so cool and everyone (so far) has been super helpful and friendly!

Answer (score 1):

To set the working directory to the Data folder:

```
setwd("Data/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @forestfanjoe and @TingleTanglBob for the help
For anyone wondering how a setwd should be formatted see this working example =)

`data_path <- paste (setwd ("Data/"),"Data", sep = "/")`

Comment: You just need `setwd("Data/")`. I'll add a separate answer...

Comment: Sorry @forestfanjoe im afraid putting setwd("Data/") alone does not fix the issue